# How to check whether a LinkButton is clicked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `LinkButton` as

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbuton" runat="server" OnClick="lnck" Text="hello">
```

Actually I have a LinkButton and a TabContainer with two tabs. When a user clicks on the tab I am clearing the data in the GridView, but when the user clicks on the LinkButton I don't want to clear the data. Thus, I want to find if the LinkButton is clicked or not.

I did something like this.

```
function onBeginRequest(sender, args) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var shHide = "0";

    $("#lnkbuton").click(function() {
       shHide="1";
      alert("clcik")
    });

    if (shHide == "0") {
        ClearHideElement();
    }
})

}
```

But this is not working.  Also the alert never gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

Controls within an aspx page generate their own ID, they don't always use the ID you give them:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx

Try this instead:

```
$("#<%= lnkbuton.ClientID %>").click(function() {
       shHide="1";
      alert("clcik")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the event's target, if it isn't the `anchor`, perform your action.

```
 $("#lnkbuton").click(function(event) {
    if (event.target != this) {
         shHide="1";
        alert("clcik")
    }
});
```

---

### [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
>   or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to
>   this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event
>   bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when
>   events bubble.

Comment: still not working ,but when i                                             $(document).ready(function(){
   var shHide = "0";

    $("#lnkbuton").click(function() {
       shHide="1";
      alert("clcik")
    });

    if (shHide == "0") {
        ClearHideElement();
    }
})

Comment: remove the function onBeginRequest(sender, args) {